# Declare Function AddPrinterConnection To run Multiple times

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a requirement in Visual Studio Visual Basic 2012 to map printers for users from a module.

I cannot find a way to do this with .net 3.5 directly so I have been using the following in a module:

```
Declare Function AddPrinterConnection Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "AddPrinterConnectionA" (ByVal pName As String) As Integer
```

I then use a for each to test something else and if it is true I use the following to add the printer:

```
AddPrinterConnection("\\printserver\" & X(1))
```

Now that works but it is very slow to map the 10 plus printers.

I would like to know if:

1. There is a way to call the function multiple times so the function would run many times making the job quite quick?
2. Or is there a better way to map network printers using VB.net that I am using.

Comment: I found that if I do this it works and runs each mapping in its own thread very quickly;

Comment: I thought I would try using threading with the following;

'
Class MainClass
        Public Shared Sub Main(Printer)
            Dim PadThread As New Threading.Thread(
                AddressOf Work.AddNetPrint)
            PadThread.Start(Printer)
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class Work
        Shared Sub AddNetPrint(Printer)
            AddPrinterConnection(Printer)
        End Sub
    End Class
'

But it did not seem to map the printers all at once. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was the following;

1. For the multi threading I used a class

   `Class MainClass
       Public Shared Sub Main(Printer)
           Dim PadThread As New Threading.Thread(
               AddressOf Work.AddNetPrint)
           PadThread.IsBackground = True
           PadThread.Start(Printer)
       End Sub
   End Class
   Public Class Work
       Shared Sub AddNetPrint(Printer)
           Dim PP As New Printing.LocalPrintServer
           If Repair = True Then
               Repair = False
               Try
                   PP.DisconnectFromPrintQueue(Printer)
               Catch
               End Try
               Try
                   PP.ConnectToPrintQueue(Printer)
               Catch
               End Try
           Else
               Try
                   PP.ConnectToPrintQueue(Printer)
               Catch
               End Try
           End If
           PP.Dispose()
           PP = Nothing
       End Sub
   End Class`
2. For mapping the queue I use System.Printing.LocalPrintServer

   `Dim PP As New Printing.LocalPrintServer
    PP.ConnectToPrintQueue(Printer)`

That all works nicely and quickly too.

Hope this helps someone.